# Is there a SFINAE-template to check if a class has no functions of any kind?

Tags: c++, class, templates, member, sfinae

I want to check if a given class has **only the following**:

- Non-static data members
- Constructor(s) (default or user-defined)
- Destructor (default or user-defined)

This type would be (at least visually declaration-wise) identical to a POD-type apart from the user-defined constructor and destructor. I've tried to find a term for this kind of type but I don't think it exists.

Is there a way to check this, using some SFINAE-hackery?

Comment: Why would you want to know that?

Comment: Absolutely not. Neither of the things that you want to prohibit has anything to do with being a POD, or AFAICT with meeting any other named or implicit requirement of the standard, so it isn't clear why you want to prohibit them.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You probably should explain why this is important for you to know.

Comment: You updated your question, but you still don't explain why you want to know that. If you would explain what you think that you could do with such a type that you can't do if it has member functions would be helpful. Maybe you have a false assumption about what you think you can do with such a type, or you are wrong about that you need this limitation.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where-s-my-sharem.  I've edited the question and removed some of the requirements that I realized weren't actually necessary

Comment: Why does member functions matter? Perhaps if you explain what you need this for it can be reopened.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. The question is quite clear, it's asking how to programmatically check whether a class contains any member functions other than SMFs. *Why* this is something the OP wants to do may be unclear, but that's not a reason to close a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no such method. Consider the following:

```
struct A { };
struct B { void UniqueFunctionName9814(); };
```

No SFINAE method can distinguish these, because you can't enumerate member function names, nor can you predict random function names. Hence `B::UniqueFunctionName9814` can't be detected, and apart from `B::UniqueFunctionName9814` the two classes are identical.

Comment: Wow. I for sure thought there would be a way to check this. How does `std::is_pod` work behind the scenes if there is no way to distinguish between `A` and `B`?

Comment: You can check the implementations. For instance, `libstdc++` implements `std::is_pod` in terms of `__is_pod` type trait provided by GCC; see https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits#L757 and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Type-Traits.html.

Comment: @JensB: It's much easier to check for specific methods, such as default constructors. But for some type traits, compiler help is necessary. Compilers _can_ enumerate class members.